# Localization of UITabBarSystemItem titles

Tags: iphone, localization, xamarin.ios, globalization

In my application written with monotouch I'm currently using a UITabBar with some UITabBarSystemItem items. All works fine except the UITabBarSystemItem item titles are not "translated". My testing device is configured to use "Italian" as language, but all UITabBarSystemItem still show the title in English.

How I can have them traslated? The apple sdk documentation says that "The title and image of system tab bar items cannot be changed." so I can image that this is done "internally" by the system, depending on the device localization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the [monotouch mailing list](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monotouch/2011-December/006971.html) I have managed how to solve this. It's quite simple:

- edit the info.plist file with the monodevelop editor (double click the info.plist file)
- go to the Advanced tab
- Add a Custom iOS Target Propertiey **Localization native development region** with the value of the culture you want

**Property**: Localization native development region **Value**: it

Comment: you can mark your question as answered so anyone else looking for the same can see a solution was found (and it's perfectly correct to accept your own answers on stackoverflow.com).

Comment: that's great! I'm just waiting the 24h time limit expiration! 6h to go!